# PersistentRegexHighlight -- a more detailed example please

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Using the existing documentation as a guide, would it be possible for someone to please give me a more detailed example of implementing the `PersistentRegexHighlight` plugin with a specific syntax (e.g., LaTeX, or a different syntax, whatever is easier).  Perhaps we could do something simple, like underline *and* change the color of `[Ff]oo`.

---

I'm confused regarding how to determine what `[Ff]oo` is.  In my regular theme file, `<string>Keyword</string>` affects the color for most of the LaTeX codes.  In the `LaTeX.tmLanugage` file, there are seven keys mentioned in the beginning -- e.g., `keyword.control.preamble.latex`.  My best guess at this point is that `[Ff]oo` could be a pre-defined language file key such as `keyword.control.preamble.latex`.

---

I am assuming that this regex code goes inside `PersistentRegexHighlight.sublime-settings`, or, perhaps the user syntax specific file (e.g., `LaTeX.sublime-settings`).

```
{
  "regex": [{
    "pattern": "[Ff]oo",
    "color_scope": "color.scope.name",
    "ignore_case": true
  }, {
    "pattern": "constant.language",
    "color_scope": "constant.language"
  }]

  "regex": [{
    "pattern": "Bar",
    "color": "00FF00",
    "ignore_case": false
  }]
}
```

---

I am assuming that this code goes into the user designated theme file.  I do not understand where we are getting `regex.highlight.one`, because it is not referenced within `PersistentRegexHighlight.sublime-settings`.

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Regex Highlight</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>regex.highlight.one</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#75715E</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The necessary disclaimer. I'm the author/maintainer of the PersitsentRegexHighlight plugin. Now that that's done here is a better example.

I thought I had included an example with "underline" but I guess I forgot. For underlining, you would add an "underline" key in the regex pattern. If you are using ST2, you cannot specify an underline style. As for color, you can specify one of two ways. The first is specifying a hex with the key `color`. This will create a new color scheme file, so this may not be desirable. The second method is to specify a scope. If you look at your `tmTheme` file, you will see a list of entries. One of the keys is `scope`, which is used as the `color_scope` name. The following exaample will highlight the regular expression `[Ff]oo` the same color as a string and underline it.

```
{
    "regex": [{
        "pattern": "[Ff]oo",
        "color_scope": "string",
        "underline": true
    }]
}
```

These settings are placed either in  PersistentRegexHighlight.sublime-settings or can be created to be project specific.

I would recommend taking a look at a tmTheme file, to gather a better understanding of what it is doing. Of course, feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: With your help, I was able to get the underline feature working.  It is my understanding that the user has a choice of highlighting `or` underlining, but not both -- i.e., underline is defined in the documentation as "[a] boolean value specifying if the specified pattern should be underlined `rather than` highlighted."  As a feature request, perhaps someday both underline `and` highlight (foreground / background)  would be possible.  I look forward to using this new plugin on a daily basis.  Thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: No problem. I'll update the documentation. I'll look into both underlining and highlighting. If you could make an issue detailing that, I'd appreciate it. :)

Comment: What an AWESOME plugin!  This is definitely one of my favorites.

Comment: @skuroda On ST2, it sadly seems that some color HEX codes are always turned to black. For example : `{"pattern": "DEBUG","color": "7500ff","ignore_case": true}`